# Regex in range but without sings

Tags: regex

This is a a text: `6:0 FC Bayern Muenchen - Werder Brem`
I want to have: `FC Bayern Muenchen`

My tries:
`\s.*-` gives `FC Bayern Muenchen -`
`\b\s.*\b-` doesn't match anything

Comment: For "FC Bayern Muenchen" the most accurate regex is `/FC Bayern Muenchen/`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
\s[^-]+
```

where `[^-]` means any character that is not `-`

Comment: `^` is the begening of line

Comment: @stakowerflol: not in a character class, where it negates the character class. Did you try it?

Comment: `\s[^-]+` gives `FC Bayern Muenchen - Werder Brem`

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `/(?<![a-z ])[a-z ]+(?![a-z ])/i`, test it here: https://regexr.com/3vv2b

Explanation:

1. Negative lookbehind of an unwanted character → `(?<![a-z ])`
2. At least one wanted character → `[a-z ]+`
3. Negative lookahead of an unwanted character → `(?![a-z ])`

Example in PHP:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(?<![a-z ])[a-z ]+(?![a-z ])/i', $test, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  FC Bayern Muenchen
            [1] =>  Werder Brem
        )
)
```